# Equivalent forms of expressions with complex numbers

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, fractions

Which expressions are equivalent to $ {1\over{(9i+z)^4}} + {1\over{(9i-z)^4}}$

Select all that apply.

$ {18i\over{(81−z)^8}}$

$ {−18i\over{(81+z)^8}}$

$ {18i\over{(81+z)^8}}$

$ {−18i\over{(81−z)^8}}$

Could someone walk me through this thoroughly? I would be incredibly grateful.

Comment: It is difficult to read the expression.

Comment: What is really the question? Do you want to factorize the expression? If you really have $z^4 - z^4$ then they cancel eachother out, so please look trough your question formulation once more.

Answer (score 0):

$$ {1\over{(9i+z)^4}} + {1\over{(9i-z)^4}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{(z+9i)^4}-\left(\frac{959}{88529281}+\frac{9360}{88529281}i\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{(z+9i)^4}-\left(\frac{1}{9409}e^{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{9360}{959}\right)}\right)$$
$$\left(\left(z^2-81\right)^2e^{4arg\left(z+9i\right)}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{9409}e^{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{9360}{959}\right)}\right)=$$
$$-\frac{e^{tan^{-1}\left(\frac{9360}{959}\right)}}{9409}+\left(z^2-81\right)^2e^{4arg\left(z+9i\right)}=$$